# Display the command being executing currently

Tags: bash, command-line

I don't recall to have explicitly placed anything in my `.bashrc` file recently, but from yesterday I am able to see the command being displayed at the prompt before getting executed. I don't know how it got switched on and when?

#### Example

```
$ ls *abc*
ls *abc*  # ---> This line is getting displayed for every command, same command as it is
abc.txt temp_abc.c
$ pwd
pwd       # ---> This line is getting displayed for every command, same command as it is
/home/mtk/temp/
```

My bash details

```
$ bash --version
bash --version
GNU bash, version 3.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2005 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

It's weird and doesn't seems to be of much use. But I would like to know how to turn this feature on and off? What command/setting does this?

Comment: `diff -u /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` might help.. checked on Debian

Comment: What is `trap`'s output?

Comment: @manatwork ah yes, DEBUG trap. didn't think of that.

Comment: @manatwork How to use it? please let me know. I am not well aware of it.

Comment: Just asked for its output for now. Anyway, if it says there is a handler set for `DEBUG` trap, then you can reset it with `trap - DEBUG`.

Comment: @manatwork How to see the output of `trap` ? I tried `trap - DEBUG` but still the command get's echo'ed.

Comment: Just type `trap` at the command line and hit Enter. Officially it would be `trap -p`, but `trap` without parameters does the same in `bash`.

Comment: @mtk If it isn't the DEBUG trap then yet another possibility is `set -x`. If somebody did `PS4=; set -x` then you would get this effect. `set +x` to disable that. If that isn't the problem, then enabling `set -x` might help you to debug it.

Comment: Don't forget `set -v`.  That output looks more like `set -v` than `set -x`, which would expand globs and have a leading `+ `.

Comment: It feels history related. If you use `!foo` to run the last command containing the string `foo`, it will output the full command it is running. But I can't think of any history option that would make this happen for all commands.

Answer (score 3):

**edit** - essentially the list of possibilities:

- if `trap -p DEBUG` is non-empty then `trap - DEBUG`
- if `typeset -p PROMPT_COMMAND` non-empty then `unset -v PROMPT_COMMAND`
- if `echo "$-"` contains `x` then `set +x`. Also your `PS4` would seem to be unset or empty.
- if `PS1` contains something weird like a command substitution redirected to stderr, set it to something sane.
- Possibly something in `~/.inputrc`, or a terminal setting (`stty`), or a misbehaving completion function.

In all of the above, figure out what sets it. Either `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/bashrc`, or some other location under `/etc` that is sometimes set by distros at compile-time.

Comment: Not working... `bash: typeset: PROMPT_COMMAND: not found`

Comment: @mtk Strange. There aren't really any other hooks in Bash that could allow this to happen. The other possibilities I can think of are a readline setting (check your `~/.inputrc`), or maybe an `stty` setting that I don't know about (try `stty sane`).